# Number of different cycles in cyclic codes with length n

Tags: coding-theory, information-theory

I am studying Information theory, coding theory in particular at the moment, and I am having trouble determining how many different cycles are defined by a certain generator polinomial?

Given a polinomial, for example $g(p)=p^6+p^3+1$, and the length of the code $n = 9$ how can I determine the number of different cycles that are defined?

I know that the cycles (001)(010)(100) and (011)(110)(101) are defined, but how can I find the rest of them?

I also wonder if there is an explicit formula that can return me the result, maybe based on the different powers in the generating polinomial?

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: What do you mean by a cycle? I don't recall seeing that term in connection with cyclic codes even though I've been around. Are you looking for a set of representatives of all codewords under the equivalence class of two codewords being cyclic shifts of each other.

Comment: Cross posted in [CSTheory.SE](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/31591/5932).

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Every cyclic code is in particular linear and hence it has a generating matrix. There is a well-known procedure how to calculate the generating matrix or parity check matrix from the generating polynomial. Once you do this, your code is just the row space of the generating matrix or the kernel of the parity check matrix.

Comment: I did this: http://bit.ly/1HsAQwB, but since I am working in modulo 2 arithmetics I did not find anything useful, although I found the answer as the dimension and codimension of the matrix, is that it?

Comment: I am confused, how did get the 4 vectors? Since $n=9$ and deg($g(p)) = 6$, your code has dimension $3$ and hence the generating matrix must have 3 rows.

Comment: Apologies, a typo, I added an extra column at the end, this is the correct one: http://bit.ly/1RhM9i6
I still do not understand how am I supposed to calculate how many different cycles are there in this code. And the correct answer is 4.

Comment: Now you have a correct basis but you need some extra work to get the code from wolfram alpha. However, the code will have $2^3 =8$ words and it is very easy to calculate those by hand. As a linear code you must include the zero word, the rows of the matrix, the sum of every two rows and the sum of all rows.

Comment: That will give me the codewords, and I am actually looking only for the cycles that are in the codewords, so I got this: http://pastebin.com/dbi3iwrX
I can say that there are only (000) and (111) as additional cycles, am I right? Are the zeros and ones always a cycle? what if there was another polinomial? I generate the codewords and just search manually for all the cycles?

Comment: Well, I was assuming that you were looking for codewords and using the term cycle instead. Now I am not sure what do you mean by that. What do you mean by "cycle" or when is a cycle defined?